# Node.js unique identifier for client for reconnections

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

I'm trying to build in a reconnection procedure for clients that lose connection. In the client js I can detect when connection is lost and periodically attempt to reconnect to the server. When I reconnect though the server will be using a new socket.

On the client this is my reconnect logic

```
var socket = io.connect(ip, {
  'reconnect': true, //will create a new socket on the server
  'reconnection delay': options.retryInterval,
  'max reconnection attempts': 10
});

socket.on("disconnect", function() {
   this.connected = false;
   this.autoretry();
});

//establish the connection - similiar to the reconnect method
socket.emit("connect", this.options);

//....
autoretry: function() {
    if(this.connected) {return;};
    var next = this.__retry *= this.options.retryScalar;
    this.socket.emit("retry", this.connect.options);
    return _.delay(this.autoretry, next, this);
}
```

The problem is each client has it's own `tls` connection to an external server and I would like to hold this connection open for a brief period; waiting to see if the client reconnects.

**Is there a good way to uniquely identify the client in node or should I create the identifier on the client and pass it to the server?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For identifying clients you,should make `socket.io` work with expressjs Sessions, each session has a unique id, and uses many additional methods to identify itself to server-side, *(cookies,headers..)*

http://howtonode.org/socket-io-auth‎

also sockets have a unique id by default when the socket object is passed to callback `io.on('connection',function(socket)` , access by `socket.id` property

For identifying a client that lost connection, and script tries to reconnect, try listening for `reconnect`,`reconnecting`,`reconnect_failed` events.

https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/wiki/Exposed-events

Comment: Is there a way to identify a reconnecting on the server because its still creating a new socket with a different `id`

Comment: Found my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9668996/does-socket-io-reconnects-re-run-connect going to make a unique client id on the browser.